# Get Documentum workflows (inbox, tasks) via CMIS?

Tags: java, workflow, cmis, documentum, opencmis

I am making a client for EMC Documentum with OpenCMIS in Java. I can create, view and get properties of documents, but I don't know how to get all workflow tasks.

Do you have any idea how to get all inbox (workflow, tasks) for a specific user? Can I use CMIS, or do I need to have a different approach?

Comment: [Apache Chemistry OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/) supports everything in the CMIS spec. Therefore, a better question is - does your system expose those objects via CMIS?

Answer (score 2):

Neither the CMIS specification nor the OpenCMIS API has a native understanding of workflows or tasks. To Gagravarr's point, if your CMIS-compliant server exposes those objects as instances of something CMIS understands (policies, folders, documents, relationships, or items) then you will be able to do it.